# Video camera starts then stops in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-streaming, mediarecorder, mediastream

**It worked fine, before,**  but now,

- 1. *it doesn't show the video on the video HTML element*.
- 2. *it starts the camera by indicating on the chrome tab, then on the white light beside the camera, but after 5 sec, it goes off*
- 3. *The recorded file also downloaded when I stopped the stream, with another button*

**Below is the code**

```
    await navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: { width: 1280, height: 720, facingMode: "user" },
      })
      .then(function(stream) {
        remotevideo.current.srcObject = stream;
        remotevideo.current.play();
        
         
        var streams = remotevideo.current.captureStream(25);
        var recordedChunks = [];
        var mediaRecorder = null
        
        console.log(streams);
        var options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(streams, options);        
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
        mediaRecorder.start();
        
        function handleDataAvailable(event) {
          console.log("data-available");
          if (event.data.size > 0) {
            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
            console.log(recordedChunks);
            download();
          } else {
            // ...
          }
        }
        
        function download() {
          var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
            type: "video/webm"
          });
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.style = "display: none";
          a.href = url;
          a.download = "test.webm";
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
        
      if (!remotevideo.current.srcObject) {
       
        mediaRecorder.stop();

      }
        
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
    });
```